# Swagger UI: Basic Auth not working with Express/Postgres app

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, passport.js

I'm building a back end with Express and Postgres, with Passport.js to authenticate users and Swagger UI Express to generate the API documentation. However, I'm having trouble with Passport's basic strategy, which I need to implement to allow users to log in on the Swagger UI and test certain endpoints.

This is my Passport.js configuration ([click here](https://github.com/DavyK17/kibandaski) for full repo):

```js
// ./routers/auth.js

const passport = require("passport");
const authenticate = async (email, password, done) => {
    try {
        const result = await pool.query("SELECT users.id AS id, users.email AS email, users.password AS password, carts.id AS cart_id FROM users JOIN carts ON carts.user_id = users.id WHERE email = $1", [email]);
        if (result.rows.length === 0) return done(null, false);
        
        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, result.rows[0].password);
        if (!passwordMatch) return done(null, false);

        return done(null, { id: result.rows[0].id, email: result.rows[0].email, cartId: result.rows[0].cart_id });
    } catch(err) {
        return done(err);
    }
}

const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, authenticate));

const { BasicStrategy } = require("passport-http");
passport.use(new BasicStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, authenticate));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    return done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try {
        const result = await pool.query("SELECT users.id AS id, users.email AS email, carts.id AS cart_id FROM users JOIN carts ON carts.user_id = users.id WHERE users.id = $1", [id]);
        if (result.rows.length === 0) return done(null, false);

        return done(null, { id: result.rows[0].id, email: result.rows[0].email, cartId: result.rows[0].cart_id });
    } catch(err) {
        return done(err);
    }
});
```

I've been looking around the Internet for potential solutions, including adding an authorization header in my Swagger options for Swagger UI Express, but nothing I've found has worked so far. Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: same problem on my end, did you find something ? i cant believe nobody has a solution in the last 4 months for this since you posted

Comment: @PirateApp Haven't looked at it for a little while but I don't think I've found a solution yet lol